# What is a thorough method to manually generate a random number between $1$ and $100$?

Tags: random

The other day, I got an  idea.  I would like to generate a random number between $1$ and $100$ , however *by hand.* You often want to use these random numbers to play games or even for practical purposes.

And only using simple tools like a desk clock and pen and paper.

What might be a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Would you consider using a fair coin or fair die?

Comment: Toss the clock in the air and see which side it comes down on :-). Repeat 7 times, and form a binary number. Ignore if the number is 100 or larger.

Comment: What sort of distribution would you like? By most definitions, you could have a random variable with only one possible value (*i.e.*, a one-element state space), even if it is somewhat uninteresting. So, write "$42$". Then, the number you wrote is your random number.

Comment: @paw88789 - Yes, that is fine also

Comment: @copper.hat -  that is brilliant... I can use it !!!

Comment: There's always https://www.random.org/ :-).

Comment: The method suggested by @copper.hat reminds me of the apocryphal story of [how to determine the height of a building using a barometer](http://wearcam.org/barometer.html). :-)

Comment: @Jens-  haha that's hilarious. Sometimes the answer is closer than we think eh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method I've always liked is to put down a bunch of parallel lines on paper and pick one somewhere in the middle, and count how many lines are on the left of it, and take that $\mod n$. The number of lines you start with of course depends on $n$ (it should be a lot more than $n$) but this is okay, since we don't need very high numbers $n$ anyway. In the case of $100$, we take $n=2$, $n=2$, $n=5$ and $n=5$, and construct the random number from these results.

Comment: i need a  bit of coffee to understand this one - will revisit in mornin

Comment: I liked this one because it seemed a more elegant solution, fast to do.

Answer (score 9):

Take your paper and cut it into $100$ smaller (equal sized) pieces.  Write each of the numbers $1$ through $100$ on the pieces.  Then mix up the pieces and pick one at random.

If you don't want to do $100$ slips, use $10$ slips, labelled $0,1,...,9$.  Pick twice with replacement for the two digits.  If you get $00$, that's $100$.

Comment: I think he should cut & fold the paper into a pentagonal trapezohedron (aka, a d10), and use it as percentile dice.

Comment: That would be very cool!

Comment: @KSmarts - How would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can find printable paper dice templates on the 'net:
http://www.timvandevall.com/templates/printable-paper-dice-template

If you don't a model with as many sides as you need,
you can always create your own in Blender,
then export a paper model by way of this pepakura script:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Put your hand on top of a piece of paper.

Step 2 : With the second hand, grab your pen and stab the first hand with it.

Step 3 : You bleed, look at your clock so you can tell the time of the accident when you call for help.

Step 4 : Mesure the area of paper covered in blood.

Step 5 : Compute ${\text{area of paper covered in blood}\over\text{total area of paper}}\cdot100$

Congratulation, that's how you generate a random number *by hand*.